# use of targetNamespace in wsdl

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

Why we use the targetNamespace in a wsdl file in web service, what is the actual purpose of targetNamespace ? I have a web service on http://example.com/webservice/catalog.php, I want to access the web service through a wordpress plugin. My plugins wsdl file is like below

```
<definitions name='shop'
  targetNamespace='http://example.com/soap/'
  xmlns:tns='http://example.com/soap/'
.
.
.
.
<service name='CatalogService'>
    <port name='CatalogPort' binding='CatalogBinding'>
      <soap:address location='http://example.com/webservice/soap-server.php'/>
    </port>
  </service>
```

I wrote to see some example below two lines, is it ok?

```
targetNamespace='http://example.com/soap/'
xmlns:tns='http://example.com/soap/'
```

I can not understand what is the actual purpose of targetNamespace in wsdl file.

Comment: here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480511.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As we know, WSDL files can import other WSDL files, there is always the possibility of a name clash. With the help of targetnamespace we can ensure that taget tag doesn't clash with anything else in your wsdl. You can read more this from... [IBM - Web Service (r)evolution Part-4](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-peer4/)

Comment: link given by Daniel is also useful for the understanding. Read that link also for more clarification.