# How to create wsdl file to access api with soap?

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

i have example xml request and xsd schema to validate the xml and url

how to create the wsdl file

```
URL http://somewebsite:10806

is this the wsdl file on my server ?
targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"

also should i change <soap:address location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/"> with 
<soap:address location="http://somewebsite:10806">

<definitions name="HelloService"
   targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <service name="Hello_Service">
      <documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
      <port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
         <soap:address
            location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/">
      </port>
   </service>
```

Comment: step 1: Google, step 2: try, [step 3: (optional) fail & try again]. If this (tried and tested) approach still doesn't work for you, ask a specific question here with code of what you've tried, and a clear desdcription of where you're stuck. As is expected of a SO question. check the help link on the top of your page, and [check SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Apache XSD to WSDL](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/xsd-to-wsdl.html).

> Is the targetNameSpace the wsdl file on my server ?
>   No; it's a namespace declaration that you make up. More info: [here in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299064/use-of-targetnamespace-in-wsdl).

Yes, you should change the soap:address from

```
<soap:address location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/">
```

to the correct address such as:

```
<soap:address location="http://somewebsite:10806/SayHello/">
```